# How to find all tables in mySQL databse having two or more columns

Tags: mysql

I want to find all the tables in mySQL database having two columns 'zoneid' and 'affiliateid'.

If i use the below query, it will give me the tables having either of the columns. I want to find out tables having both columns

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('affiliateid','zoneid')
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA='openx';
```

i tried writing query like

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('affiliateid') AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('zoneid')
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA='openx';
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE  COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%affiliateid%' union
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%zoneid%' `

Comment: It is producing the same result, showing tables which have either 'zoneid' or 'affiliateid' but not both

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME ='affiliateid' union SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'zoneid'
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME ='affiliateid' union all SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'zoneid'
```

or similar to

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%affiliateid%' union all SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%zoneid%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE id IN 
( SELECT id FROM syscolumns WHERE name = 'affiliateid' )
and id in 
( SELECT id FROM syscolumns WHERE name = 'zoneid')
```

OR

```
select t.name
from sys.tables t 
inner join sys.columns c on c.object_id=t.object_id 
where c.name in ('zoneid','affiliateid')
group by t.name
having count(distinct c.name) = 2
```

Comment: It doesnt work, it is giving me tables which have only zoneid, or only affiliateid but not having tables with both the columns, i need to find tables having both the columns in a single table

Comment: @JyotsnaGupta:- Please check the updated answer. It will surely work. Thanks

Comment: Query : SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE id IN  ( SELECT id FROM syscolumns WHERE name = 'affiliateid' ) and id in  ( SELECT id FROM sy...
Error Code : 1146
Table 'openx.sysobjects' doesn't exist

Comment: @JyotsnaGupta:- It should be 'sysobjects.openx' not 'openx.sysobjects'

Comment: @JyotsnaGupta:- Added one more option of getting the result. Both are working for me.!

Comment: I think my database is not recognizing sys.tables , sys.columns, object_id,

Comment: can you please explain me?

Comment: @JyotsnaGupta:- What you want to get explanation for? Hope you have checked: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use.

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, count(*) AS `Tcount` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.`COLUMNS`
WHERE `column_name` IN ('affiliateid','zoneid')
GROUP BY table_schema, table_name
HAVING `Tcount` = 2
```

**Tcount** should be equal number of columns you looking for. If it's so, then your table have all required columns

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C1.TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C1
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C2
ON  C2.TABLE_NAME=C1.TABLE_NAME
AND C1.COLUMN_NAME='zoneid'
AND C2.COLUMN_NAME='affiliateid'
AND C1.TABLE_SCHEMA='openx' AND C2.TABLE_SCHEMA='openx'
```